# Background and Foreground

Tags: c++, image, opencv, background

I would like to extract the background alone and store it; rather than the foreground object (in a single Bitmap if possible)  or a sequence of bitmaps if that not possible with a single Bitmap (and need to take in the consideration the first Bitmap rather than use it as a reference), I just need a library on opencv or any equivalent that is my question; while I still dont have a full idea about the scheme to write a code so in the current time I just ask for an Opencv library to write a full C++ code. Thank you.

Comment: whats your input and what do you consider as foreground/background? typically for motion segmentation you can use something like the average of all images as a background. Maybe you better post a sequence of images and show us what you want to achieve/extract.

Comment: 1st of all thanks for your reply, actually my input is a sequence of any BMPs (extracted from any normal video i.e. not from a camera), and am not interested in foreground now, am interested in background, I need to extract them from each image to trace a certain features from them (high texture area, low freq,..etc) and I need to deal with each Image (BMP) alone, the averaging of all the back grounds is a v.good idea but in my case the changing in the Illumination will certainly harm (this include other changes in the seq. (s.as a bird suddenly appears on the sky). BMP seq is big to upload.

Comment: have a look at ViBe background modeling (and foreground extraction). But be aware that it is patented. In general, foreground extraction and background modeling are related and you might need both to extract one of them stable. - I've never been in Heidelberg yet ;)